# Child controller's navigation controller conflicts in UI with parents navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

Steps:

1. Embedd a navigation controller to entry point controller(ViewController.swift) of main application.
2. Set entry point to navigation controller.
3. Add an extra view controller in storyboard and link it to ViewController1.swift file.
4. Call this function from IB action of ViewController file.

```swift
func addChildController(childController : UIViewController) {

    let navigation = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: childController)
    navigation.view.frame = self.view.frame
    navigation.willMove(toParent: self)
    self.addChild(navigation)
    navigation.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
    self.view.addSubview(navigation.view)
    navigation.endAppearanceTransition()
    navigation.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

---

**Result:** - Extra space comes between the navigation bar and the below UI, which ties with safe area of  view controller.

[image]

Comment: Why you need to use another `UINavigationController` for `childController`?

Comment: That is a very small part of my program. I am using Child controller to display a dialogue in it. The child controller is base controller for my @emrcftci

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your view controller embedded in a Navigation Controller, you should use the same for your child view controllers.

In your case, you have added a Navigation Controller through storyboard, then in `func addChildController(childController : UIViewController) {` you are adding a new navigation controller again.

I think instead of using this `addChildController()`, you should use this for pushing next view controller:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func pushVC(vcName : String) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```